# how to extract H1,H2,H3 tag values from html using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

1.HTML

```
<div id="page-filter1">
**<h3>**
    Browse Category
**</h3>**
<ul class="mt-accordion multiple">
   <li id="phdesktopbody_0_phdesktopfilterbycategory_0_liAllProduct" class="cls-8dcbcbac-2fef-4231-9641-d61818abe0e0 item-1 odd first odd">
        <a id="phdesktopbody_0_phdesktopfilterbycategory_0_hypAllProducts" href="/en-us/products">All Products</a>
    </li>
```

2.

```
<div class="span12">
    <h3 class="onelayout-heading">
        <strong><em>Callout <sub>&copy;</sub>itle<sup>x</sup></em></strong>
    </h3>
</div>
<div id="phdesktopbody_0_phdesktopflexiblepromo_0_phdesktoppromocontentarea6b299d9421684ceaaed7c23ebee57f57_0_panelSubheadlineandCTASection" class="span7 pull-left">
```

i've more than 1 H2 ,&H3 tags in each page, 
The class name and description changes each and every times ,pls help me on identifying the tags and extract the values from it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Arjun Vc please do like below if the class name and description changes each and every times same beloe piece of code will work.

```
driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.com"); // link to your  web page

        // working with H1 H2 .... tags 

        String TagToWorkWith = "h1"; // here simply change the tag name on which you want to work
        List<WebElement> myTags =  driver.findElements(By.tagName(TagToWorkWith));

        // now extracting the vale 
        // this for loop will print/extract all the values for tag 'H1'.
        for(int i=0;i<myTags.size();i++){
            // extracting tags text
            System.out.println(TagToWorkWith + " value is : " + myTags.get(i).getText());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Rajnish, this is exactly what i needed .

Comment: your welcome it helped you then plz mark it as your answer